# Why is the output of the following program showing compile time error?

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

Why is the output of the following program showing compile time error?
Please explain "lvalue required"

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    int a=5;
    printf("%d", ++a++);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not the output of the program, it's an error message from the compiler while attempting (and failing) to compile your program.

Comment: The short version is, the language is protecting you from shooting yourself in the foot. The long version is a tad more complicated, and are you in C or C++?

Comment: The `++` operator increments a variable, storing the incremented value back into the same variable, and returns a value.  So the first `++` increments your variable `a`, and returns a value.  But then the second `++` tries to increment that value, but it can't, because there's no variable to store the incremented value back into.  It's sort of like saying `5++` — totally meaningless.

Comment: @3636 Rewa Kher Just write a proposal to the C Standard Committee to make such construction ++a++ valid.:)

Comment: In case you are wondering what an "lvalue" is: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category

Comment: @SteveSummit: That is not a useful rule for students at this level. Source code is just a string of text, and a string of text has no inherent meaning. Humans give it meaning by relating it to things and specifying rules. The rules could just as easily say that `++a` or `a++` produces an lvalue and that `++a++` does have a meaning. OP would need to know what the rules about meaning are before they could apply a rule not to write meaningless code, and that is essentially what their question is.

Comment: "lvalue required" basically means "I need a variable to store something into".  You'll probably get the same error if you write things like `5 = a`, or `5 += 1`, or `5++`, or `++5`.  These all fail because `5` is a simple value, not a variable you can store values in.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I want to stand by that argument, because I *do* think that `++a++` is self-evident nonsense, I really do, but the fact that C++ defines it rather demolishes my argument. :-(  Comment deleted.

Answer (score 4):

A language-lawyer proof explanation is a bit lengthy, here's an attempt at a simplified explanation:

The "l" in "lvalue" comes from "left" as in a value that can appear on the left hand side of an assignment operation, which includes many named variables:

```
int a;
a = 42;  // a is an lvalue and can be assigned to
```

Now due to operator precedence the expression `++a++` is parsed as `++(a++)`. And since `a++` modifies `a` "later" but, as expression, evaluates to the current value of `a` it "returns" a copy of this current value of `a`, a *temporary* value.

This temporary value is unnamed (it is not `a`) and it's not an lvalue, wherefore it can't be assigned to.

You can't write `a++ = 42` because you'd be assigning to the temporary *value*, rather than a variable, and for the same reason you can't write `++a++`.

Again, you'll have to dive much deeper, and also give yourself some time to develop an intuitive feeling for what an lvalue is, then this will become much clearer.